# Current Position topic? (frontier_exploration)

Tags: ros, frontier-exploration, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello! I am running a Turtlebot3 with ROS on Ubuntu v16.02, and using the package frontier_exploration. I would like to use the bot's current position as a condition in my python script, so my plan is to subscribe to the topic and proceed from there. However, I cant seem to find the topic to which the current position is being published. Without this, I'm not sure how to tell the bot to stop once it is within a certain distance of it's origin position (0, 0, 0). Any help with this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295771/current-position-topic?-(frontier_exploration)/) by [AmateurHour](https://answers.ros.org/users/36117/amateurhour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 95 on 2018-06-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Frontier Exploration itself is not going to give you a pose estimate, but there are a number of other tools to help you, including TF!

You can create a TF listener to get the map -> robot base frame transform. If you care about it in bash, there's a rosrun that will help you as well with tf echo. `rosrun tf tf_echo /map /base_link`

http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Tutorials/Writing%20a%20tf%20listener%20(C++)

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1